# How to make Rails acceptable value out of JavaScript's array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to generate the value for a hidden field in a Rails form with JavaScript.

```
pickedImages = document.getElementsByClassName("picked_images");
imagesIds = []

for (var i = 0; i < pickedImages.length; i++) {
  imagesIds.push(pickedImages[i].id) 
}


document.getElementById('user_post_materials').value = imagesIds;
```

I need it like: value="150 152 146"

But when I try to make it out of JS array I get: value="150,152,146" which causes saving as a string in the database and further bugs.
I tried

```
imagesArray = imagesIds.join(' ')
document.getElementById('user_post_materials').value = imagesArray;
```

But it still gives a wrong value: value="150, 152, 146" (Commas still present)

Comment: How are you saving it in the database? If you use `.join(' ')`, split the string by space character when you get it, so it can be an `array`.

Comment: "*which causes saving as a string in the database and further bugs*" - your rails script definitely needs to do some validation on the inputs. It would probably also involve parsing the input string, so it shouldn't be too hard to make it accept commas as delimiters instead of spaces. However, instead of defining your own format rules, you might want to go for a standard representation like JSON where parsers and serialisers are available in both languages.

Comment: @chsdk I'm saving it through posting form. Which string do you suggest to split? I have html collection (pickedImages) and array (imageIds). And I need to get string out of it.

Comment: @Bergi That's a good idea! I'll try.

Comment: @AlexanderGorg I meant before trying to save it the database take the value and split it, but you are psoting it with the form so use JSON as suggested by Bergi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bergi' and Roby Rodrigues' ideas I made it through.
So I did the following:

```
imagesArray = imagesIds.join(' ').replace(',', '');
```

I let this question unaccepted for anyone who comes up with something better.

Answer (score 1):

You could try turning it into a string during this assignment:

```
document.getElementById('user_post_materials').value = imagesArray.join(" ");
```